# Woocommerce Category Sort Dropdown

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, sort, dropdown

In Woocommerce Category page default sort dropdown has like below options.
[image]

My question is what/how products sort  by Popularity ? **Not a code**  What is the **measurement** ? like if sort Price: Low to High,then we know those  product sort Low price to High then How about **Popularity** ?

Comment: popularity — you can choose this option if you want products to be sorted from most popular to the least popular ones;

Comment: please check this link code:https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/f356269e6fd2e53b1d803d5e7cd146151be68049/includes/class-wc-query.php#L494

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Sort By Popularity' filter sort products based on total sales of product

Answer (score 0):

Well the option **Sort by Popularity** will sort the products based on **Total sales**. It means the product will sort from **Higher sales** to **Lower sales**.

You can get more idea from below code :-

```
$args['meta_key'] = 'total_sales';
add_filter( 'posts_clauses', array( $this, 'order_by_popularity_post_clauses' ) );
```